# Integrating alfresco with existing infrastructure

Tags: process, integration, alfresco, internal

We have many custom and off-the-shelf applications to manage document mgmt like scanning, indexing, storage,workflow etc in our company,

We want to get started with Alfresco to completely manage our document management process.
This requires integration with external databases, interfacing with existing Java infrastructure and internal Oracle DB.
Since there is huge amount of information for Alfresco on the web, i want to know how do we go ahead with Alfresco. Any specific tools of Alfresco i should be using and how easily can i revamp our existing process with Alfresco.
Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for Oracle database is [only provided by the Enterprise version](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Database_Configuration#Oracle_example) of Alfresco.

In order to let Alfresco be the one an only hub of your document processes, and to benefit from its features, you will most likely need to migrate your preexisting content into the Alfresco repository. Then, you'll need to integrate external systems in some ways. There's a [good tool](http://code.google.com/p/alfresco-bulk-filesystem-import/) to do massive import of content into Alfresco.

Alfresco is quite powerful when it comes to extension/integration points, the most useful are usually [Web Scrips](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts), which provide a REST API that allows you to control your content, workflows, life, universe and everything using plain HTTP calls. There is a huge number of Web Scripts available OOTB, but you can easily add custom ones, both [Javascript](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts#Java-Backed_Implementations) or Java implementation are directly available, and [PHP](http://www.springsurf.org/sites/1.0.0-RC2/spring-webscripts-addons/spring-webscripts-addon-php/), [Groovy](http://www.springsurf.org/sites/1.0.0-RC2/spring-webscripts-addons/spring-webscripts-addon-groovy/) and [Clojure](https://github.com/skuro/spring-webscripts-addon-clojure) as external plugins.

Several other possibilities are provided to expose content to external systems or users, such as [WebDAV](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/File_Server_Configuration#WebDAV_Server_Configuration), [CIFS](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/File_Server_Configuration#SMB.2FCIFS_Server_Configuration) (Alfresco as a shared drive), [SOAP](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Content_Management_Web_Services), ....

Comment: Thanks Skuro, this is useful info for me.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to skuro post I would add that Alfresco has a growing community around the world who are working daily with new features. One example is the MetaDBConnector Alfresco component, which allows you to link information from your Oracle database (and other RDBMS) to the documents stored in Alfresco, easly.
Is available for download from Alfresco Addons http://addons.alfresco.com/addons/alfresco-metadbconnector-component.
Developed and maintained by VenziaIT (http://venzia.es).
Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Mule ESB, the open source esb tool has connectors to Alfresco as well as nearly all leading db vendors including Oracle.

http://www.mulesoft.com/cloud-connectors/alfresco-integration-connector